# how to send a link as a parameter in php laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i have the following code

```
eo.changeState = function(clicked_button) {

    // get the selected app path
    var app_path = getAppPath(clicked_button);

    // get the selected app status
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/get_app_status/' + encodeURIComponent(app_path),
        context: clicked_button
    })
};
```

and am using the route

```
Route::post('get_app_status/{app_path}', [
    'as' => 'get_app_status',
    'uses' => 'LocalDataController@getAppStatus'
]);
```

the problem is when i click the button, i get the following error

```
 POST http://localhost:8000/get_app_status/%2Fmedia%2FData%2FCode%2Fproject%2Fdone%2FServiceManager 404 (Not Found)
```

i think its because the %, but i don't know a javascript way to fix this problem, except using a replace method, by just replace all the '/'s on javascript, then get them back with str_replace in php.

is there a valid fix on javascript ?

Comment: Maybe instead of including `app_path` in the URL, you should send it in as a parameter.

Comment: @mopo922 that what i think am doing, can you give me an example on code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the app path as POST parameter

```
eo.changeState = function(clicked_button) {

    // get the selected app path
    var app_path = getAppPath(clicked_button);

    // get the selected app status    
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'app_path': app_path},
        url: '/get_app_status/',
        context: clicked_button
     });
};
```

Route would be like this:

```
Route::post('get_app_status', [
    'as' => 'get_app_status',
    'uses' => 'LocalDataController@getAppStatus'
]);
```

Finally controller function:

```
function getAppStatus() {
    $app_path = Input::get('app_path'); 
}
```

Comment: i've never used data, on my ajax request, it's a nice tip to have, tnx @apsdehal

Answer (score 2):

Instead of including `app_path` in the URL, try sending it as a parameter:

```
eo.changeState = function(clicked_button) {

    // get the selected app path
    var app_path = getAppPath(clicked_button);

    // get the selected app status
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'app_path': app_path},
        url: '/get_app_status'),
        context: clicked_button
    })
};
```

Then the route is just:

```
Route::post('get_app_status', 'LocalDataController@getAppStatus');
```